# Change to admin view on successful login in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I've a MVC application with nodejs and angular js as front end, I've a login page which have a  different top menu than  other pages 
How to switch between these header to show in the view

In angular js login controller, I'm calling the service which checks for username and password  returns JWT token if the login is successful. Everything is fine, But how  to render the admin page

I wanted to know how to change the entire view rather than changing the the part of the view in angularjs

Comment: use ui-router, change state&view on login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use promise and $location, or ui-router. When you post request to your server you can define success callback in your promise. Inside that callback everything what you need is redirect user. for example:

```
$scope.auth = function(credentials) {
    myService.login(credentials).then(function(res/*response*/) {
       $location.path('/'); 
       or $state.go('app.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it saved my day and this first response which i got helped me